# Append . to fish shell path

Tags: path, fish

Despite the abundance of questions on how to set the path on the fish shell, I haven't been able to find the answer to this seemingly very simple one :

I want to append `.` to my path (because I dislike typing `./` all the time, and I'm not a sysadmin, so there's no real security concern here)

The problem is that everything I've tried with `fish_add_path --universal --append` fails somehow :

- `.` `"."` `'.'` `\.` : add cwd to path
- `"\."` `'\.'` : add nothing at all to path

I want to add a literal `.` dot to my path. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use `fish_add_path`. From https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/fish_add_path.html

> Components are normalized by `realpath`. Trailing slashes are ignored and **relative paths are made absolute**

Use `set PATH $PATH .`

Comment: So, this works. It's kinda stupid that it's the only solution, but it's basically what I came to as well :`set fish_user_paths "."`, and then prepend the other things I had in there 